# Подключение css к php

Tags: php, html, css

Имею следующую структуру лендинга. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Лендинг разбит на модули header, footer. Для каждого модуля своя папка, в папке модуля содержится файл с разметкой модуля и папка assets. В папке assets папки css, js и img, в которых содержатся файлы для конкретного модуля: стили, скрипты и картинки соответственно.

В разметке модуля файлы подключаю относительно файла разметки. Например:
Файл разметки header, подключаю css таким образом:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При открытии модуля header отдельно все стили подключаются корректно.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Чтобы собрать сайт подключаю модули в корневом файле index.php следующим образом:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И теперь при включении корневого файла index.php header отображается вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что делать? Что не так?

Comment: Смотреть в Dev Tools браузера, подключаются у вас стили вообще. Может там на половине или вообще всех стилях 404

Comment: Дело в том, что я подключаю файлы относительно файла модуля, а когда делаю инклуд этого файла в корневой, он пытается искать относительно корневого, можно ли это как то исправить? Чтобы он всё равно искал относительно того файла, который подключаю.

Comment: Используйте полный путь и не будет у вас никогда подобных проблем... сами себе трудности создаете и доблестно с ними боретесь.. ппц.. P.S. в 2023 так создавать сайты не хорошо, так в 2008м делали еще

Comment: А что вы предлагаете? Так очень просто компоновать лендинги, просто верстаем лендинги, в которых постоянно повторяются блоки, поэтому решили сделать модульную структуру

Comment: Подгрузил модуль, стили поменял, и красота

Comment: @Freez Фриз Я предлагаю подучится...)

Comment: Ок) Итак учусь, я просто устроился в небольшую веб-студию, меня так попросили сделать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваша проблема в том что пути доступа к файлам у вас относительные, и они некорректно подключаються в вашей сборке. Это вопрос не про `php`, это про [подключение](http://htmlbook.ru/samhtml/ssylki/absolyutnye-i-otnositelnye-ssylki) или как описано [тут](https://htmlacademy.ru/blog/html/links) Надо "плясать" от корневого `index.php` или пишите полные пути к файлам или корректно отобразите те что в `href` (Возможно там `href="./и так далие"`)

Answer (score 0):

Лучше убрать в начале путей до файлов по одной точке.

```html
<link href="./header/assets/css/normalize.css"></link>
<link href="./header/assets/css/style.css"></link>
```